# Is there a way to define human in the loop tasks

Tags: airflow

In apache airflow: What I want is to show a small web ui / form to a human to let him make a decision that we cannot implmement in code (yet). I haven't found anything in the docs or with google for that yet - so is there any architectural problem that would prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point in time, there is no such thing in Airflow.

(thinking out loud) You could set up a form yourself, which sets a `True`/`False` somewhere, such as a file or database. In Airflow, you'd then use a sensor to check whether True or False is set. A few examples; you could use the SqlSensor for a database query, the S3KeySensor for a file to be present on AWS S3, or the generic PythonSensor to provide your own condition.

Comment: That more or less confirms what I assumed from not finding anything. I guess the way to emulate this would then be:

1. Add a 'human job' to a queue where humans can look for a job (and / or send out some message to them)
2. Block on some bool that signifies that the human has done the task (in the way you mentioned
3. Add some web application that allows humans to take the job and which marks them as done afterwards.